Undefined control sequence on almost every line of code
    1 \backslashdocumentclass[12pt]{article}
>>  2 \usepackage{lingmacros}
>>  3 \usepackage{amssymb}
>>  4 \usepackage{amsmath}
>>  5 \usepackage{tree-dvips}
>>  6 \begin{document}
    7
>>  8 \section*{Notes for My Paper}
    9
   10 Don't forget to include examples of topicalization.
   11 They look like this:
   12
>> 13 {\small
>> 14 \enumsentence{Topicalization from sentential subject:\\
>> 15 \shortex{7}{a John$_i$ [a & kltukl & [el &
>> 16   {\bf l-}oltoir & er & ngii$_i$ & a Mary]]}
>> 17 { & {\bf R-}clear & {\sc comp} &
>> 18   {\bf IR}.{\sc 3s}-love   & P & him & }
   19 {John, (it's) clear that Mary loves (him).}}
   20 }
   21
>> 22 \subsection*{How to handle topicalization}
   23
>> 24 I'll just assume a tree structure like (\ex{1}).
   25
>> 26 {\small
>> 27 \enumsentence{Structure of A$'$ Projections:\\ [2ex]
   28 \begin{tabular}[t]{cccc}
>> 29     & \node{i}{CP}\\ [2ex]
>> 30     \node{ii}{Spec} &   &\node{iii}{C$'$}\\ [2ex]
>> 31         &\node{iv}{C} & & \node{v}{SAgrP}
   32 \end{tabular}
>> 33 \nodeconnect{i}{ii}
>> 34 \nodeconnect{i}{iii}
>> 35 \nodeconnect{iii}{iv}
>> 36 \nodeconnect{iii}{v}
   37 }
   38 }
   39
>> 40 \subsection*{Mood}
   41
   42 Mood changes when there is a topic, as well as when
   43 there is WH-movement.  \emph{Irrealis} is the mood when
   44 there is a non-subject topic or WH-phrase in Comp.
   45 \emph{Realis} is the mood when there is a subject topic
   46 or WH-phrase.
   47
>> 48 \end{document}

This code is my .tex file and >> on particular lines show undefined control sequence errors. (This error is suggested by my language server texlab). When I run pdftex .tex file I get the same on every line suggested by texlab. It is not that something is wrong with this .tex file, but it is that I tried 15 different tex files and every file had many undefined control sequence errors. In the section below my system specs are given.
I am using termux in my android phone, my editor is neovim and for language servers I use coc-texlab. I tried asking to chatgpt which suggested to reinstall latex in my termux as some packages are not correctly installed so I did using below steps:
Pkg install texlive-installer
termux-install-tl

And yes, I did delete texlive completely before re-installation. I suspect that this is happening because of texlab server. Without texlab server none of this happened and it was working fine before I started to make changes. Can someone help me fix this with the texlab server ?
I installed it simply by doing pkg install texlab as it was available on termux and also CocInstall wasn't working for some reason.
Below are some of lines of my tex file log:
% This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 
% 2024/Termux) (preloaded format=pdf    latex 2024.5.17)  17 MAY 2024 
%  13:05

  2 entering extended mode
  3  restricted \write18 enabled.
  4  %&-line parsing enabled.
  5 **bruh.tex
  6 (./bruh.tex
  7 LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
  8 L3 programming layer <2024-04-11>                                                             
  9 ! Undefined control sequence.
 10 l.1 \backslashdocumentclass
 11                            [12pt]{article}
 12 ?                                                                                             
 13
 14 ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
 15
 16 See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
 17 Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 18  ...
 19                                                                                              
 20 l.1 \backslashdocumentclass[12pt]{article}                                                                 
 21                             
 22 ?                                                                                            
 23 Missing character: There is no [ in font nullfont!                                           
 24 Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!                                           
 25 Missing character: There is no 2 in font nullfont!                                           
 26 Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!                                           
 27 Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
 28 Missing character: There is no ] in font nullfont!
 29 Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
 30 Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
 31 Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
 32 Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
 33 Missing character: There is no c in font nullfont!
 34 Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
 35 Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
 36
 37 ! LaTeX Error: \usepackage before \documentclass.
 38
 39 See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
 40 Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 41  ...

 % Below these there were a lot more undefined control sequence errors. I 
 % am not able to copy paste due to how big the file is: 
 % Few more lines : 
 99 LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
 100
 101 ! LaTeX Error: The font size command \normalsize is not defined:
 102                there is probably something wrong with the class file.
 103                                                                                                       
 104 See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
 105 Type  H <return>  for immediate help.                                                                 
 106  ...                                                                                                  
 107                                                                                                       
 108 l.6 \begin{document}                                                                                  
 109                                                                                                       
 110 ?
 111 ! Undefined control sequence.
 112 l.8 \section
 113             *{Notes for My Paper}
 114 ?
 115 ! Undefined control sequence.
 116 l.13 {\small
 117
 118 ?
 119 ! Undefined control sequence.
 120 l.14 \enumsentence
 121                   {Topicalization from sentential subject:\\
 122 ?
 123 ! Undefined control sequence.
 124 <recently read> \shortex
 125
 126 l.15 \shortex
 127              {7}{a John$_i$ [a & kltukl & [el &
 128 ?
 129 LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
 130 (Font)              <7> on input line 15.
 131 LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
 132 (Font)              <5> on input line 15.
 133 ! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
 134 l.15 \shortex{7}{a John$_i$ [a &
 135                                  kltukl & [el &
 136 ?
 137 ! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
 138 l.15 \shortex{7}{a John$_i$ [a & kltukl &                                                             
 139                                           [el &
 140 ?
 141 ! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
 142 l.15 \shortex{7}{a John$_i$ [a & kltukl & [el &
 143
 144 ?
 145 ! Undefined control sequence.
 146 l.16   {\bf
 147             l-}oltoir & er & ngii$_i$ & a Mary]]}
 148 ?
 149 ! Misplaced alignment tab character &.


Please edit your question: Remove line numbers and provide compilable code. Other users should only have to copy your code and paste it into their own editor.

Your document seems to start with the word backslash

Highlight your code and use the {} button to format it properly, so that it looks like what you have on your computer.  But as Ulrike points out, the first command should be \documentclass, not \backslashdocumentclass.

Welcome! Only the first error usually matters. If all of your files start \backslashdocumentclass, all will give the same initial error followed by a stream of other errors which you can ignore until you've corrected that first one.

It should  be \documentclass, not  \backslashdocumentclass[12pt]{article}.  This avoid \usepackage  that is a valid command, but now out of place, and so on. If you are new in LaTeX, start always by a \documentclass{article} \begin{document} hello \end{document} and then add  things only step by step, checking in every step that your document is still working. This will help you to understand how LaTeX works and the  error messages when you make only a mistake.

If I fix your code in the following way
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lingmacros}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tree-dvips}

\newcommand{\smallenumsentence}[1]{\enumsentence{\small#1}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Notes for My Paper}

Don't forget to include examples of topicalization.
They look like this:

\smallenumsentence{Topicalization from sentential subject:\\
\shortex{7}{a John$_i$ [a & kltukl & [el &
\textbf{l-}oltoir & er & ngii$_i$ & a Mary]]}
{ & \textbf{R-}clear & \textsc{comp} &
  \textbf{IR}.\textsc{3s}-love   & P & him & }
{John, (it's) clear that Mary loves (him).}}


\subsection*{How to handle topicalization}

I'll just assume a tree structure like (\ex{1}).

\smallenumsentence{Structure of A$'$ Projections:\\ [2ex]
\begin{tabular}[t]{cccc}
    & \node{i}{CP}\\ [2ex]
    \node{ii}{Spec} &   &\node{iii}{C$'$}\\ [2ex]
        &\node{iv}{C} & & \node{v}{SAgrP}
\end{tabular}
\nodeconnect{i}{ii}
\nodeconnect{i}{iii}
\nodeconnect{iii}{iv}
\nodeconnect{iii}{v}
}

\subsection*{Mood}

Mood changes when there is a topic, as well as when
there is WH-movement.  \emph{Irrealis} is the mood when
there is a non-subject topic or WH-phrase in Comp.
\emph{Realis} is the mood when there is a subject topic
or WH-phrase.

\end{document}

and run LaTeX on the file like
latex zaid && dvips zaid -o && ps2pdf zaid

I have no problem at all.
The first error is what counts most and in your case it was about
\backslashdocumentclass

being undefined. Stare a bit at it and you'll see why.
Finally:

\bf and \sc have been deprecated for about 30 years; there's no excuse in using them;

there are better tools for trees that don't require dvips;

{\small<material>} isn't the best way to go, see how I defined a helper command for the job.



I suggest forest instead of trees-dvips.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lingmacros}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\newcommand{\smallenumsentence}[1]{\enumsentence{\small#1}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Notes for My Paper}

Don't forget to include examples of topicalization.
They look like this:

\smallenumsentence{Topicalization from sentential subject:\\
\shortex{7}{a John$_i$ [a & kltukl & [el &
\textbf{l-}oltoir & er & ngii$_i$ & a Mary]]}
{ & \textbf{R-}clear & \textsc{comp} &
  \textbf{IR}.\textsc{3s}-love   & P & him & }
{John, (it's) clear that Mary loves (him).}}


\subsection*{How to handle topicalization}

I'll just assume a tree structure like (\ex{1}).

\smallenumsentence{Structure of A$'$ Projections:\\ [2ex]
  \begin{forest}
    s sep=1.5cm
  [CP,
    [Spec]
    [C$'$
      [C]
      [SAgrP]
    ]
  ]
  \end{forest}
}

\subsection*{Mood}

Mood changes when there is a topic, as well as when
there is WH-movement.  \emph{Irrealis} is the mood when
there is a non-subject topic or WH-phrase in Comp.
\emph{Realis} is the mood when there is a subject topic
or WH-phrase.

\end{document}


